# How enable SSO in FastAPI using Keycloak and AAD as identity provider?

Tags: python, single-sign-on, openid-connect, fastapi, swagger-ui

I need to enable SSO for the FastAPI, so our users can SSO if they  want to use Swagger UI. At the moment, the UI passes a token to the FastAPI and FastAPI checks the validity of the token through using fastapi-keycloak. If a user needs to use Swagger UI, they submit a username and password which gets authenticated by Keycloak. I would like to change this part to use SSO.

I was able to use AAD for SSO by using this library https://github.com/Intility/fastapi-azure-auth

Was able to use both AAD and Keycloak using this approach:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme),azure_auth: Optional[User] = Depends(azure_scheme)):
    if azure_auth:
        return azure_auth.name
    else:
       check with the keycloak....
```

but have difficulty to only have Keycloak in place for SSO.

My `utils.py` is as follows:

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from auth.client import GetKeycloakClient
from fastapi import Depends,HTTPException,status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from keycloak import KeycloakAuthenticationError
from constants import constants
import logging
from ast import literal_eval

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth/")#

async def authenticate_user(client, username, password):
    try:
        print("I am in authenticate_user line 16")
        token_info = client.token(username=username, password=password)
        return token_info
    except KeycloakAuthenticationError as ex:
        print("user not aucthenticated inside authenticate_user")
        
        return ex.response_code


async def validate_user(client, token):
    try:
        print("I am in validate_user line 28")
        user_info = client.userinfo(token)
        #print('utils:line 27 of utils.py:')
        #print(user_info)
        return user_info
    except KeycloakAuthenticationError as ex:
        print("user not aucthenticated inside validate_user")

      
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    print(" I am in get_current_user line 39")
   
    consts=constants()
   
    load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ".env"))
    server_url = os.environ.get('KEYCLOAK_ISSUER')
    client_id=consts.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID
    realm_name=consts.KEYCLOAK_REALM
    client_secret_key=os.environ.get("KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET")

    client = GetKeycloakClient(
        server_url=server_url,
        client_id=client_id,
        realm_name=realm_name,
        client_secret_key=client_secret_key
    ).client_connection()
    user = await validate_user(client, token)
        
    if isinstance(  user, (bytes, bytearray)):
        print("user not aucthenticated inside get_current_user line 63")
        user_decoded_dict = literal_eval(user.decode('utf-8'))
        if type(user_decoded_dict)==dict and 'error' in user_decoded_dict:
            print(user_decoded_dict['error'])
        
        raise HTTPException ( detail="Not authenticated",
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})
    elif user['sub'] :
        #print (user['sub'])#user['preferred_username']
        pass
    else:
        print("user not aucthenticated inside get_current_user")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Not authenticated")
        
   
    return user
```

and in the `main.py`:

```
@app.get("/keycloak/")
async def keycloak_ep(request:Request,token: str = Depends(get_current_user)):
```

and `client.py` is:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakConnectionError, KeycloakOpenID
import logging

class GetKeycloakClient(object):
    print (" I am in GetKeycloakClient line 5 ")
    if 'auth.client.GetKeycloakClient' in str(object.__name__):
        #print (object.__name__)
        pass;
    else:
        print (" empty obj_name as ",object.__name__)
    def __init__(self, server_url: str, client_id: str, realm_name: str, client_secret_key: str):
        print(self, object)
        self.server_url = server_url
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.realm_name = realm_name
        self.client_secret_key = client_secret_key

    def client_connection(self):
        try:
            print ( "I am in GetKeycloakClient line 14")
            client = KeycloakOpenID(
                server_url=self.server_url,
                client_id=self.client_id,
                realm_name=self.realm_name,
                client_secret_key=self.client_secret_key
            )
            print ( "I am in GetKeycloakClient line 20")
            return client
        except KeycloakConnectionError as ex:
            print ( "I am in GetKeycloakClient line 22")
            return ex.error_message
```

Comment: Thanks Helen for the edit and improving the question's quality